# Algorithm for parsing nested ternary expressions

Tags: swift, algorithm

I am trying to develop a solution that can take a ternary expression that may be nested many times and be able to convert it to a truth table.

Im struggling to get my head around how to find the relevant bits of the ternary because obviously they use the same symbols. Can anyone help me understand this issue?

As an example I could have an expression like:

```
InEmerg ? Red : (Failed ? Black : White)
```

I want to be able to parse it so that I could turn it into a truth table

| RESULT | RED | BLACK | WHITE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| InEmerg | True | False | False |
| Failed | - | True | False |

I would like to do the solution in Swift but pseudocode would be enough for me to understand.

Comment: Your truth table seems wrong. Don't overthink this. If InEmerg is true, the expression in parentheses is not even evaluated.

Comment: In Ternary expressions the term before the `?` (InEmerg, Failed) are the conditional/truth values and the following two terms are the possible *results*.  You seem to be treating them the other way around, as though the possible result values (Red, Black, White) are the conditional truth values.

Answer (score 1):

Your truth table does not match the problem. Red/black/white are results, not booleans in this context.
For your example a truth table would look like this:

| InEmerg | Failed | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| True | True | Red |
| True | False | Red |
| False | True | Black |
| False | False | White |

To generate a truth table for any (nested) ternary expression just insert any possible combination of variables into it and observe the result.

Variables here are `InEmerg` and `Failed`, **not** Red, Black, White.